# psql how to turn group by functions into columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have the following table:

```
ID    Day    Count
1      '1'     1
1      '2'     2
1      '2'     7
2      '2'     4
2      '2'     3
```

and I'm doing the following query:

```
select ID, Day, sum(Count) from test_table group by ID, Day
```

and I get the following table:

```
ID    Day    Count
1      '1'     1
1      '2'     9
2      '2'     7
```

what I want is

```
ID    Day1    Day2
1      1       9
2      0       7
```

How do I do that?

Comment: sounds like a job for `crosstab`

Comment: I dont have admin privileges to use crosstab

Comment: @user1871528 . . . Are the `day` values strings?  Do they contain single quotes?

Answer (score 2):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select ID, 
       sum(case when day = 1 then count else 0 end) as day_1,
       sum(case when day = 2 then count else 0 end) as day_2
from test_table
group by ID;
```

Comment: Answer is correct, only missing quotes for day values, like this `select ID, sum(case when day = '1' then count else 0 end) as day_1, sum(case when day = '2' then count else 0 end) as day_2 from test_table group by ID;`

Answer (score 1):

Use `crosstab()` from the [`tablefunc` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tablefunc.html).

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  $$select ID, Day, sum(Count)
   from foo2
   where Day = '1' or Day = '2'
   group by ID, Day
   order by 1,2$$)
AS ct(ID int, day_1 BIGINT, day_2 BIGINT);
```

Comment: I dont have admin privileges to use crosstab

Comment: You need to go to a `psql` console and write: `create extension tablefunc;`

Comment: If you don't have access to crosstab, go ahead and write calculations on a HOST LANGUAGE such as Java, C# or Python.